# Sencha Themer : UI totally stuck then unable to open my theme

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, extjs7

I am currently trying to test the developpment tools that provides Sencha : Sencha Architect and Sencha Themer. So I just installed the last accessible versions with my licence :

- Sencha Themer : v1.3.6.157
- Sencha Architect : v4.2.6.425
- Sencha CMD : v7.0.0.40

Then, I created my own theme for "Classic Toolkit" based on "Triton", I changed the base color, some buttons properties and created 2 UIs (one for a Panel and an other on for a Menu), nothing else.

I imported my small theme in Sencha Architect applying my UIs to the Panel and Menu I wanted, all was good and pretty.

But after that, I came back to Themer and no action was possible...interface was totally stuck.

I tried to close it and reopen my theme but I have this error message :

```
Error: unknown definition for mixin named undefined : C:/Users/XD/Documents/protoUsabilis/packages/local/Usabilis1/sass/save/Ext/panel/Panel.scss:2
    unknown definition for mixin named undefined : C:/Users/XD/Documents/protoUsabilis/packages/local/Usabilis1/sass/save/Ext/panel/Panel.scss:2
        at SenchaCmd._closeHandler (C:\Users\XD\bin\Sencha\Themer\resources\app.asar\node_modules\sencha-cmd\index.js:236:32)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:290:19)
        at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
        at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
        at Socket. (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
        at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:501:12)
```

Do you know what is going wrong?

I am a little surprised to have this type of problem after such a short use and I don't know if it is possible to use these tools in a work context.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade to Sencha Themer : v1.4 and check if works?

Comment: Unfortunatly no, our sencha licence has already expired and we only have access to tools versions that I mentionned. 
It was only a try and I think we won't use theses tools. We are used to developp our frontend without